# Pull a mime type out of a URI using PHP

Tags: php, data-uri

So after searching through multiple documentation sources I'm still no closer to figuring out how to extract the Mime type from a data URI that has already been processed and stored in a DB.

[image: image of URI]

That is a quick snap shot of the exact data I have to work with.  I just want a dynamic way to always get the "image/png" part which may change with each image in the DB.

I'm using PHP.

Comment: in php 5.4+ `return explode(':', explode(';', $str, 2)[0], 2)[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but you could do:

```
// assume you've set $image_uri to be the URI from the database
$image_parts = explode(";", $image_uri); // split on the ; after the mime type
$mime_type = substr($image_parts[0], 5); // get the information after the data: text
```

It could be done with regular expressions, but I'm not good enough at them to come up with it.

Comment: Gabe this worked perfectly.  I was trying to do it with a reg expression, but couldn't get it to stop.  Thanks!

Comment: sometimes the less elegant ways are the best

Comment: This will fail on `data://`-style URI's (although those *are* nonstandard...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the elegant solution, using the [`mime_content_type`](//php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function.

```
return mime_content_type($data_uri);
```

Just pass the URI to the function, and it'll work ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php)).